# How to set bold in ComboBox only in presentation line, not in whole drop down list (WPF)?

Tags: c#

I have in my `DataGrid` `ComboBox` implementation. Also I have a `IsColorCalibFolderBold` property by this property `ComboBox` know when it should represent data in bold style and when no.

So, my property

```
        public bool IsColorCalibFolderBold
        {
            get { return _IsColorCalibFolderBold; }
            set
            {
                _IsColorCalibFolderBold = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();   
            }
        }
```

and my `.xalm`

```
...

              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox 
                                                x:Name="Cb_color_calibration"
                                                SelectionChanged="Cb_color_calibration_SelectionChanged"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColorCalibrationFolders}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedColorCalibrationFolder}">
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UIRepresentation}" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsColorCalibFolderBold}" 
                                                                         Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ComboBox.Style>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

...
```

And all is works fine here

[image]

Text is really bold when property set true and otherwise when false, but problem is here

[image]

When I open drop down list, so all items also bold... I need that only representation is bold, but dropdown list itself not.

How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle`, so as part of the ComboBox definition:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
  </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```